# Javascript Render Manager with SAP UI5: Create Custom Control

Tags: javascript, sapui5, render, custom-controls

A bit of full disclosure, I am not a JavaScript expert. I am working extending a feature but when I tried using afterRendering function on line 251. I got the error message "it is not a function". I was trying to create the afterRendering function using SAP API but I seem to be running into problems. The alternative is to use "document.createElement". This works but then I got the message when I hover line 252 that "Direct element Creation, create a custom control instead (sap-no-element-creation). My guess is afterRendering function should be about 2 to 5 lines but I have no idea how to go about things. Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting to get more details. What are you trying to accomplish? What's the source code of your custom control? Do you have a small running example?

Comment: I am trying to build a table. Using document.createElement(line 252) does the job alright. The problem is that when I hover over line 252, I get the the message "Direct Element creation, create a custom control instead". This was why I introduced the afterrendering function. This is function is meant to be the custom control. I have just tried to build but I got sap-no-element-creation. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: There is a table control in UI5 already. Why don't you use that? Basically the WebIDE tells you to use the existing UI5 controls or to create a custom UI5 control. It is a bad practice to write your own HTML when developing UI5.

Comment: @Marc, are you suggesting using document.afterRendering().createELement("tbl") should be dumped. I just stumbled on afterRendering. It is an event under class sap.ui.core.HTML in the SAP API. I would appreciate alternative suggestion as I am just new to SAP API and trying to figure my way round it. I am creating this table on a page which I would then export as an email.

Comment: I just stumbled across some UI5 custom control generator. This is for HTML. Does anyone have an idea if there exists a generator based on XML? I could just convert the XML to HTML and then use with the generator. The end goal is to create an HTML table with headers such that I can click on a add button on each row to be able to populate my row, hence my table with this add button. I have this table on a page working fine with document.createElement. Hopefully the custom control generator should fix the error message as a result of using document.createElement.

Comment: This already exists in UI5

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableEditable

Please please please follow any basic tutorial on UI5. What are Views, Controllers, Controls, Models etc: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218

Answer (score 1):

In SAPUI5 / OpenUI5 (UI5), it is best practice to not create HTML DOM elements directly but to use custom controls. All controls have a renderer that converts the control data to DOM elements using the UI5 API so that they are only rendered again when they've actually changed (along with other benefits).

The error you're seeing in WebIDE is an ESLint rule that tries to suggest this behaviour.

I would read up on custom controls as part of the tutorial [here](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db).

And in depth resources [here](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/8dcab0011d274051808f959800cabf9f)

However, as other commenters have suggested, it might be better to start with a standard control. UI5 has a library of controls included and you can play with them (and see their code) [here](https://ui5.sap.com/#/controls), maybe either a [sap.m.List](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.List) or a [sap.m.Table](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table) control?.

Comment: I will ramp up on my understanding of the issue. Thanks a lot